Zustandspassiv bilden
Hallo Leute meine Frage: Kann man den Satz

Vor einem halben Jahr ist ein Wettbewerb veranstaltet worden

auch im Zustandspassiv schreiben? Wenn ja, welcher Satz ist richtig?

Das Zustandspassiv wird nur angewendet, wenn als das Resultat einer Handlung ein veränderter Zustand der Welt zu beobachten ist. Beispielsweise kann die Goldmedaille vergeben sein (jemand hat sie im Schrank liegen), aber ein Wettbewerb kann nicht veranstaltet sein.

Das Zustandspassiv beschreibt üblicherweise das Resultat einer Handlung oder einen Zustand, der erreicht wurde: Ich öffne eine Tür, und danach ist die Tür offen oder geöffnet.

Ich habe die Tür geöffnet.


Die Tür ist von mir geöffnet worden.

und dann im Zustandspassiv

Die Tür ist geöffnet.

Aber was sollte das Resultat sein, wenn man einen Wettbewerb veranstaltet? In welchen Zustand sollte der Wettbewerb dadurch kommen? Ich kann hier keine Möglichkeit erkennen, diesen speziellen Satz als Zustandspassiv zu formulieren.
Mit ähnlichen Sätzen ginge es natürlich, zum Beispiel:

Er hat den Wettbewerb beendet.


Der Wettbewerb wurde von ihm beendet.


Der Wettbewerb ist beendet.


Nun, man kann schon was konstruieren (wie immer): "Das Bier war getrunken, der Wettbewerb veranstaltet und die Sieger gekürt, das Komitee konnte sich auflösen"
